# Программа для вывода месяца по первым 3м буквам

Tags: c

Нужно создать программу которая в качестве аргумента принимает первые 3 буквы месяца и выводит этот месяц и его количество дней на консоль.

```
struct month months[12] =  
{
    {"January", "jan", 31, 1},
    {"Fabruary", "fab", 28, 2},
    {"March", "mar", 31, 3},
    {"April", "apr", 30, 4},
    {"May", "may", 31, 5},
    {"June", "jun",  30, 6},
    {"July", "jul", 31, 7},
    {"August", "aug", 31, 8},
    {"September", "sep", 30, 9},
    {"October", "oct", 31, 10},
    {"November", "nov", 30, 11},
    {"December", "dec", 31, 12},

};
printf("Input the first 3 letters of month: ");
scanf("%s", source);
for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
{
   if(strncmp(source, months[i].abrv, 3) != 0)
        {
            printf(" %s: Month %s has %d days\r\n",months[i].abrv, months[i].name, months[i].days);
            break;
        }
    else
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Comment: В чем состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: Используйте `strftime` и [`strptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Логика нарушена. Ветка кода

```
else
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

не должна выполняться после каждого неудачного сравнения, а только в случае, если ни одно из сравнений не было успешным.

И, насколько я понимаю, успешный результат `strncmp` здесь нулевой.

Для случая ,когда нужно игнорировать регистр, @NewView подсказал также функцию [strncasecmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncasecmp)

Возможное исправление (не тестировал):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
   if(strncmp(source, months[i].abrv, 3) == 0)
        {
         printf(" %s: Month %s has %d days\r\n",months[i].abrv, months[i].name, months[i].days);
         break;
        }
}
 if (i==12)  //всё прошли, ничего не нашли
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Comment: [`strncasecmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncasecmp) тогда уж :)

Comment: @NewView Это зависит от формулировки задачи - вдруг строго нужно. Добавлю на всякий случай.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает.

Comment: @Alex Belz Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом)